# rJava from Clojure

Tags: r, clojure, rjava, clojure-java-interop

I am trying to use R from Clojure with [rJava](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html) as shown [here](http://www.codophile.com/how-to-integrate-r-with-java-using-rjava/). I have the following:

```
(ns prototype.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [prototype.dataGraph :as dg])
  (:import [org.rosuda.JRI Rengine]))

(defn -main
  "Program main entry point."
  [& args]
  (new Rengine (into-array String ["--no-save"]) false nil)
  (println "Hello."))
```

then, I get the stacktrace

> Cannot find JRI native library! Please make sure that the JRI native
>   library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jri in java.library.path

So it seems I did not specify the lib location correctly...

And the Java constructor is of the form:

```
Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);
```

My *project.clj* file:

```
(defproject prototype "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-expand-resource-paths "0.0.1"]]
  :resource-paths ["/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/jri/JRI.jar" "/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/jri/JRIEngine.jar" "/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/jri/REngine.jar"]
  :main ^:skip-aot prototype.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

Can rJava be successfully used with Clojure?

Comment: rJava is used to call Java from R, not the other way around.

Comment: @Hong Ooi Well, if I understood what this guy does, it seems doable... http://www.codophile.com/how-to-integrate-r-with-java-using-rjava/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, so the issue was that the shared lib was not correctly specified in the java.library.path. This works:

```
(defproject prototype "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-expand-resource-paths "0.0.1"]]
  :resource-paths ["/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/jri/JRI.jar" "/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/jri/JRIEngine.jar" "/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/jri/REngine.jar"]
  :jvm-opts [~(str "-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/jri/:" (System/getenv "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))]
  :main ^:skip-aot prototype.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```